# Intercept all requests without a locale in the url and redirect them to a proper url with local while using next-intl

Tags: next.js

This middleware is only intercepting requests to '/'. What about the rest of the routes?

```
import { createIntlMiddleware } from "next-intl/server";

export default createIntlMiddleware({
  locales: ["en", "de", "fr", "es"],
  defaultLocale: "en",
});
```

I expect every request to be redirected to a page with its locale in the path

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `localePrefix: 'always'` option:

```
import { createIntlMiddleware } from "next-intl/middleware";

export default createIntlMiddleware({
  locales: ["en", "de", "fr", "es"],
  defaultLocale: "en",
  localePrefix: "always"
});
```

This will redirect requests from the root to always result in a prefixed path:

- `/` -> `/en`
- `/about` -> `/en/about`

Note that this is available in releases >=2.13.0.

Comment: Also if you want to catch all routes with locale prefixed. You should add this to middleware.ts config => matcher: ["/((?!_next|.*\\..*).*)"]